# How to read a file in another jar file?

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource, manifest.mf

I am running a GUI application (A.jar). Then I add a plugin (B.jar) to this GUI(A.jar).
Now I want to access the manifest.mf file in B.jar. I tried B.class.getResourceAsInputStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"). However, what I got is the manifest.mf in A.jar, not in B.jar.

Anyone can give me some hints on this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: How do you add the plugin? What is B.class?

Comment: You may try likethis:- public void readXmlFile(){ 
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar2);
JarEntry entry = jarFile.getJarEntry("/test.xml");
InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);}

Comment: Since jar is zip, try unzip B.jar(or exclude needed file) from running A.jar and read what you need.

Comment: `class.getResourceAsInputStream` will search your current directory, which will be your calling method's class file's location directory (A.jar). You will probably need a `classloader` to load a class from B.jar and then call `.getResourceAsInputStream()`

Comment: @RahulTripathi While I have no doubt it's possible, if the OP is loading the Jar via a custom class loader, it would a lot easier to just reference it via its class loader ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer:- Yes I agree thats why I just commented it. Even I was not very sure ;)

Comment: Use [`JarFile.getManifest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getManifest%28%29) for this.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Seems together we have a possible answer ;)

Comment: Thanks guys. I got the solution finally. Just as the one 
Joop Eggen posted. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the case that the general class loader will take the path the comes first on the class path, and evidently A.jar comes first, before B.jar.

```
String someUniqueResourceInBJar = "...";
URL url = B.class.getResource(someUniqueResourceInBJar);
url = new URL(url.getPath().replaceFirst(someUniqueResourceInBJar + "$", "")
    + "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
url.openStream();
```

The url will be something like "jar:file://.../B.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".

---

***Alternatively getting the class URL:***

```
URL url = b.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Comment: I still trying to get my head around this.  If `B` is within the class path, then simple using `getResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") should work on it's own, there should no need to create a new `URL`, because the URL becomes unknown - there's no guarantee that the new `URL` actually points to a valid resources...besides, `B#getResource` would have already returned a valid URL reference...just seems confusing to me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer The confusing part is, that the class loader of B tries to resolve the path. If the path is absolute, "/...", then all jars are considered, loaded by that class loader or its class loaders. With a relative path "META-INF/..." that would not happen, but the B.class should be in the root (no package). BTW `getClassLoader().getResource` uses an absolute path and requires **no** `/`.